# How can I watch a demo of my last competitive match?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I just had an excellent 4-headshot round with a scout that I'd like to take another look at. Is there a way to do this?

I know you can record demos manually, but I don't want to always record my matches as that takes a lot of effort and disk space. Is there functionality similar to lastreplay.rep in SC:BW that autosaves your last demo and overwrites it automatically?

Comment: CS:GO does not automatically record demos...... But you can record one manually by typing "record <name" into console, stop recording by typing "stop", and play it back by typing "playdemo <name>". Keep in mind- Demo's are very buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer is out of date, here is the current way to do it:

[image: Click Watch]

1. Click to the Watch button on main menu.

[image: Click to the Your Matches button]

2. Click to the Your Matches button.

[image: Pick a match, and hit the download button]

3. Pick a match from the left-hand side of screen, and hit the download button on right top.

The demo will be now downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

In a recent update (October 2013) a watch feature was added to CS:GO. Now it is possible to download and then watch your eight last competitive matches.

This video shows you how to do that:

Comment: Can I run it faster? or jump to a certain moment?